# Can 'what' be the object of the main clause and the object of a dangling modifier of the subordinate clause at the same time?

Tags: grammar, clauses

Here's such a sentence:

> His dad needs to find **what** magazines he grew up reading.

The 'what' here is the [object](https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/sentencestructure#:%7E:text=this%20case%2C%20%22good.%22) of the main clause.

> His dad need to find ***what** magazines* (object).

The subordinate clause here is:

> **what** magazines he grew up reading.

The problem is, 'what' is not directly the object of the subordinate clause, but the object of the [dangling modifier](https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/c.php?g=465757&p=3437978) of the [subordinate clause](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/subordinate_clause.htm).

The subordinate clause without dangling modifier:

> (**what** magazines) he grew up.

The dangling modifier:

> reading (**what**) magazines.

So you see, 'what magazines' here is

1. the object of the main clause,
2. the object of a dangling modifier of the subordinate clause.

Is this sentence grammatically wrong? I've never seen sentences like this before. It sounds natural to me, though.

---

Notes: I didn't learn grammar in English, so some of the names may be misused.

For those who may ask, this sentence is inspired by a line of [a recap](https://youtu.be/rfqE5AMICY4?t=415). The original sentence is

> I think his dad needs more time to know his son, understand his preferences, and maybe find what magazines he grew up reading.

Comment: I don't follow you. _What magazines he grew up reading_ is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) functioning as complement of _find_. _What magazines_ may be considered object of reading. The antecedent of "he" is ambiguous between "his dad" and some unspecified person ("his son"?)

Comment: @BillJ My grammar books told me that 'what magazines', when served as an object in the main clause, can only be the object or subject of the subordinate clause, not the object of a dangling modifier of the subordinate clause.

Comment: I wouldn't say that _what magazines_ is object in the main clause. In the main clause _what magazines he grew up reading_ is complement of _find_. Within the subordinate clause _what magazines_ is object of _reading_.

Comment: @BillJ But reading is a dangling modifier.

Comment: @BillJ You wouldn't find a sentence like this in a grammar book, say [*Grammar of Spoken and Written English*](https://benjamins.com/catalog/z.232) by  
Douglas Biber, etc.

Comment: The last line of your question strongly implies that the antecedent of "he" is "his son". And the object of "reading" is "what magazines", so the clause seems unambiguous to me.

Comment: @BillJ I'm not asking for the meaning. I'm doubting the grammatical correctness of the sentence structure. Seems no grammar book deals with this structure.

Comment: I've already explained the grammar, which is fine.

Comment: This question should belong to *english.stackexchange*. Can anyone help to move it there?

Comment: Note that it should be "find out", not "find".

Comment: @BillJ Yeah, I think so, too. It's just the original sentence uses 'find'. XD  The [speaker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfqE5AMICY4&t=415s&ab_channel=MrRecapREBORN) seems to be a native speaker, not sure, tho.

Answer (score 1):

There's no dangling modifier in your sentence.

"His dad needs to find what magazines he grew up reading."

The deep structure of the sentence is something like this:

> His dad needs to find [something]. His son grew up reading [some magazines].

First step is to replace "some magazines" with the pronoun "what magazines":

> His son grew up reading [what magazines].

Next, front the pronoun:

> [what magazines] his son grew up reading __________.

Finally, connect the two clauses together:

> His dad needs to find [what magazines] he grew up reading _________.

We don't pronounce the _________ after "reading", but it represents the place the object "what magazines" comes from. "What magazines" is the direct object of "reading", so "reading" isn't dangling.

Comment: 'Reading magazines' may not be dangling, but it does modify 'grew up'.

Comment: The rare thing is, 'what magazines' is in the modifying part of the subordinate clause. I've never seen this situation before. No matter what grammar book you check, things like 'what magazines' is the subject or the object of the subordinate clause

Comment: @Michael When textbooks introduce these structures around the elementary or pre-intermediate level, they purposefully use simple sentences so as not to confuse the lower level students those books were written for. Have you ever seen a textbook that **says** the pronoun must be the subject or object of the **main verb** in the subordinate clause, or did you just infer that because the examples weren't complex enough?

Comment: Two points: "what magazines" is a noun phrase, not a pronoun. And it should be mentioned that _what magazines he grew up reading_ is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question).

Comment: @gotube You have a point.

Comment: @BillJ Can you say more about "what magazines"? I mean, it does the work of an interrogative pronoun even though it's two words. Would you agree that it's "pronominal"? I don't even know if that's a word, but I think you know what I mean.

Comment: "What magazines" is an NP with the noun "magazines" as head and the interrogative determinative "what" as determiner. The NP functions as object of "reading" in prenuclear position. The meaning can be glossed as "His dad needs to find the answer to the question 'What magazines did he grow up reading?'"

Comment: @BillJ Thanks so much. Would you say it's also correct to call "what" a pronoun?

Comment: No: as I said in my last comment, this "what" belongs to the word class (POS) 'determin**ative**' (interrogative). Its function is that of 'determin**er**'.

Comment: Incidentally, it should be "find out", not "find". I've pointed this out to the OP.

Comment: @BillJ Got it. And how about "*... find out **what** he grew up reading.*" Is "what" a pronoun there?

Comment: Yes, it is a pronoun. It is not a dependent of a noun.